# Excel not recognizing values and outputting "0"

Tags: excel, indexing, null, excel-indirect

I am using the below formula in excel. It works for half the data and returns "0" for the other half.
Some of the cells that I reference in the formula are joint strings and numbers (2 cells combined).

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!"&K2&":"&K2),MATCH(H2,Prices!$C:$C),0)
```

I have carried out the following checks but to no avail, I am baffled!

- Checked for empty space
- Highlight the cells and did the Data>Text to columns
- Changed the format to text
- Tried putting an apostrophe at the beginning of the referenced cells.

I had no luck with any of these, any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Try Formulas > Formula Auditing > Evaluate Formula and see what part is not producing the desired result and fix that. The Worksheet name should have ' apostrophe in the start and end of the reference before the !. The refence should be created as 'Prices'!A2:A5

Comment: hI @VipulKarkar, I have tried the evaluate formula. it seems the problem is with MATCH(H2,Prices!$C:$C),0). I have inserted the apostrophe as you said however still now luck.

Comment: It looks like the formula is having problems reading in decimals. it works just fine for whole numbers

Comment: Which part contains Decimals? Match? If yes, add 0 at the end to enforce the Exact match. MATCH(H2,Prices!$C:$C,0)

Comment: @VipulKarkar Great thank you, this worked! I had positioned the "0" incorrectly.

Comment: I just added this as an answer, you can accept the answer so this question will not reflect in Unanswered status and will help others to search more efficiently.

Comment: Just want to add that adding `'` around the sheet name is only required if the sheet name contains a space, otherwise it's optional.  `'Prices'!A2:A5` or `Prices!A2:A5` will work, but `Prices 1!A2:A5` will fail while `'Prices 1'!A2:A5` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at the exact match, update your [match](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) formula to include 0.

```
=MATCH(H2,Prices!$C:$C,0)
```